# Enabling cross domain tracking with Google Analytics on different properties

Tags: google-analytics

We have 2 sites running google analytics, each on different properties in GA.
On each of them, we have configured cross-domain tracking as explained in Google Analytics help pages on the subject.

When clicking from site A to site B, cookie is correctly passed in the _ga URL parameter.

The issue is that in Site B, client coming from site A are still seen as coming from site A as referral and not from the original site from which they arrived on Site A, for instance Adwords ppc campaign.

We added Site A and Site B to the referrer exclusion list but then Source is identified as Direct and not Adwords

Is analytics cross domain tracking only possible with a single property for Site A and Site B ?

If yes, is it possible to configure this single property while not changing anything to the current property configuration on Site A and Site B ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is analytics cross domain tracking only possible with a single property for Site A and Site B ?

Yes, it's only possible with a single property. This is because client IDs are not shared between properties for user-privacy reasons.

> If yes, is it possible to configure this single property while not changing anything to the current property configuration on Site A and Site B ?

You could use two trackers on each site. One tracker that treats them both as a single property and then one tracker that treats them as separate properties.

This isn't necessarily an ideal solution if you'd planned this from the beginning, but it's a good way to add new reporting capabilities without losing historical data.

Comment: I believe Client IDs are shared between properties, because they'll both be reading them from the _ga cookie, or the linker plugin, and I don't think either of those specifies a UA number. In any case, I've definitely seen two properties share IDs across domains.

Comment: Thanks Philip, we'll try to implement the 2 tracker thing, although we hoped we wouldn't have to go there. J Brazier, have you been able to make this works with 2 property IDs and still get traffic affected to Adwords ? If yes, any idea on how to make this work ?

Comment: @JBrazier client IDs are (by default) shared by all properties for a particular domain, but they are not (by default) shared for any particular property across multiple domains: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Comment: @Philip ah, I understand what you mean now, thank you.